# How do I browse images from firebase storage without hardcoding the variables?

Tags: swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I have uploaded images in Firebase Storage and want to download and display them in xcode - an arrow changing from one picture to another. I have successfully managed to do so, but only by hardcoding the image-storage variables. I have only included code to give you an idea of what I mean. Images are stored in imageRef. ImageArray hold the variables. The function is clicking the arrow to loop the array with currentImage, which changes with every click. So, what I want to do is changing the image viewed without having to hardcode the image variables in imageRef. Something like ImageArray[nextFireBaseStorageImage] :P Thing is, there are a lot of pictures, also I want to be able to update the storage without having to hardcode in xcode every time. Any ideas? Grateful for all help! :D

```
imageRef = storageRef.child("image/IMG_0007.jpg")                           
imageRef2 = storageRef.child("image/IMG_0015.jpg")
imageRef3 = storageRef.child("image/IMG_0017.jpg")
ImageArray = [self.imageRef, self.imageRef2, self.imageRef3] 

self.lastImage = self.ImageArray.count
var currentImage = 0

ImageArray[self.currentImage].getData(maxSize: 1*1000*1000){ (data, error) in       
    if error == nil {
        self.ImageUI.image = UIImage(data: data!)                                  
    } else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
    }
} 

@IBAction func arrowToNextRecipe(_ sender: Any) {

    self.currentImage = self.currentImage + 1                                                     

    if self.currentImage == self.lastCookieImage {
        self.currentImage = 0
    }

    self.cookieImageArray[self.currentImage].getData(maxSize: 1*1000*1000){ (data, error) in     
        if error == nil {                                                                                                                                                                  
            self.recipeImageUI.image = UIImage(data: data!)                    
            } else {                                                                         
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)                                           
        }                                                                                       
    }                                                                                           
}
```

Comment: You would generally store the links (references) to the images in your Firebase database. So the process would be to observe a Firebase parent node which would contain all of the references to your images. Those refs would be stored in an array which would be used as a dataSource for a tableView displayed to the user. As new images are added, store those new references within the Firebase database.

Comment: So I have the images in the storage, then add their URLs to the database? From there I create an array in xcode using the database references? How would the array look like? Could you give an example?

Comment: It would just be an array of urls to iterate over know what images to load. If you want to get creative, implement a structure or class that stores the id of the firebase node (the key), the name or description of the image and the url. Then store those structures in the array.